# Strongly Connected Components Using Kosaraju Algorithm

Tags: version-control

I am having problem understanding how to find output times of vertices. Here's the connections:
0 to 1
1 to 2
2 to 0
2 to 3
3 to 4
4 to 3
4 to 6
3 to 5
5 to 6
6 to 7
4 to 6.[Directed graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJtCu.png)

At first I've found finish time of all vertices starting with node 3.
0
1
2
3
5
4
6
7(finish time of nodes in a stack, the first node with 0 finish time at the bottom). The strongly connected components are
0 2 1
3 4
5 7 6(there's 3 SCC).
Now i'm confused how to find the output time. Do I make any mistakes in my calculation?

Comment: What does this have to do with "version-control" tag?